# ruby on rails : error with rake db:migrate on mysql

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am having a trouble while rake db:migrate command . i have around 90 fields in my table nd the database i am using is mysql on windows 7.. while migrating it gives me error that row size too large please change the column size, i even changed the limits to (65535) of the fields in the column and it still gives me the same error . i need to use mysql only please advise me what should i do to over come this problem.

Comment: Wow, 90 fields in one table.. man you seriously need to normalise!

Comment: Yeah, I agree with @Sam. 90 fields is way too much. Break that up into smaller tables first, then we can talk about which column exactly is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is a maximum `varchar` size combined for the entire table, you will have to use `TEXT` columns instead. This applies to InnoDB tables, I'm not sure about others.